# render different image on two different JFrames

Tags: java, swing, jframe, render, multiple-monitors

I'm making a program kinda like powerpoint, but with two different outputs. I can't find out how to do it. I can make two `JFrames` in fullscreen but i can only render on one of the `JFrames`.

Comment: Do you need both of them in full screen exclusive mode?  If you only want to render to one, what's point of the other?

Comment: i wanna render on both of them sry for my bad English